# how to replace excerpt with full posts on WP

Tags: php, wordpress

First thing first, i'm new with WP and i'm also not very good with `PHP`.
anyway, i use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-page/ to group all the posts that i create inside a specific page and it works good.

Now, i'd like to change the code so that all my posts displayed on the page are not excerpt but the full posts.

I need a full explanation on how to do that cause as i said above i'm new both in `wordpress` and `PHP`.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. One is to go to the *Reading* Settings in the Administration interface and select your desired option under *For each article in a feed, show…*.

The other way is to hardcode this in the theme itself. Open the template file (index.php for example) and replace `the_content` or `the_excerpt` with `the_content`.